# How to represent Graham's number in programming language (specifically python)?

Tags: math, numbers, biginteger

I'm new to programming, and I would like to know how to represent Graham's number in python (the language I decided to learn as my first).  I can show someone in real life on paper how to somewhat get to Graham's number, but for anyone who doesn't know what it is, here it is.

So imagine you have a 3.  Now I can represent powers of 3 using ^ (up arrow).  So 3^3 = 27.  3^^3 = 3^3^3 = 3^(3^3) = 3^27 = 7625597484987.  3^^^3 = 3^7625597484987 = scary big number.  Now we can see that every time you add an up arrow, the number gets massively big.
Now imagine 3^^^^3 = 3^(3^7625597484987)... this number is stupid big.

So now that we have 3^(3^7625597484987), we will call this G1.  That's 3^^^^3 (4 arrows in between the 3's).

Now G2 is basically 3 with G1 number of arrows in between them.  Whatever number 3^(3^7625597484987) is, is the number of arrows in between the 2 3's of G2.  So this number has 3^(3^7625597484987) number of arrows.

Now G3 has G2 number of arrows in between the 2 3's.  We can see that this number (G3) is just huge.  Stupidly huge.  So each G has the number of arrows represented by the G before the current G.

Do this over and over again, placing and previous number of "G" arrows into the next number.  Do this until G64, THAT'S Graham's number.

Now here is my question.  How do you represent "the number of a certain thing (in this case arrows) is the number of arrows in the next G"?  How do you represent the number of something "goes into" the next string in programming.  If I can't do it in python, please post which languages this would be possible in.  Thanks for any responses.

Comment: You need to specify what you want to *do* with the number before you can select an appropriate representation. Depending on the purpose, the string `'G64'` could be a perfectly acceptable representation...

Comment: here's an answer from code golf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35926/39486

Comment: Well, a basic approach would be a recursive function. The function which calculates 3^^^3 calculates 3**function_which_calculates 3^^3. Look up recursive algorithms. These kind of algorithms are very important (and a lot of people need a lot of time to unterstand this). Additional remark: even if you implement this, you can't calculate more than 4 or 5 iterations. You won't be able to do this with the computing power of all the computers in the world.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a recursively defined number, which can be expressed using a *base case* and a *recursive case*. These two cases capture the idea of "every output is calculated from a previous output following the rule '____,' except for the first one which is ____."

A simple canonical one would be the factorial, which uses the base case 1! = 1 (or sometimes 0! = 1) and the recursive case n! = n * (n-1)! (when n>1). Or, in a more code-like fashion, f(1) = 1 and f(n) = n * f(n-1). For more information on how to write a function that behaves like this, find a good resource to learn about recursion.

The G1, G2, G3, etc. in the definition of Graham's number are like these calls to the previous results. You need a function to represent an "arrow"  so you can call an arbitrary number of them. So to translate your mental model into code:

> "[...] we will call this [3^^^^3] G1. [...] 'The number of a certain thing (in this case arrows) is the number of arrows in the next G' [...]"

Let the aforementioned function be arrow(n) = 3^^^...^3 (where there are n arrows). Then to get Graham's number, your base case will be G(1) = arrow(4), and your recursive case will be G(n) = arrow(G(n-1)) (when n>1).

Note that arrow(n) will also have a recursive definition (see [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)), as you showed but didn't describe, by calculating each output from the previous (emphasis added):

> 3^3 = **27**.
>
> 3^^3 = 3^3^3 = 3^(3^3) = 3^**27** = **7625597484987**.
>
> 3^^^3 = 3^**7625597484987** = scary big number.

You might describe this as "every output [arrow(n)] is 3 to the power of the previous output, except for the first one [arrow(1)] which is just 3." I'll leave the translation from description to definition as an exercise.

(Also, I hope you didn't actually want to represent Graham's number, but rather just its calculation, since it's too big even for Python or any computer for that matter.)

Answer (score 1):

```
class GrahamsNumber(object):
    pass

G = GrahamsNumber()
```

For most purposes, this is as good of a representation of Graham's number as any other one. Sure, you can't do anything useful with `G`, but for the most part you can't do anything useful with Graham's number either, so it accurately reflects realistic use cases.

If you do have some specific use cases (and they're feasible), then a representation can be tailored to allow those use cases; but we can't guess what you want to be able to do with `G`, you have to spell it out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

G1 (3^^^^3) is far larger than the number (3^7625597484987) you have listed. firstly, the number 7625597484987 comes from working out the number of 3's in a tower when trying to calculate 3^^^3. However, the calculation of 3^^^3 only gives you the number of towers that need to be slogged through when calculating the much larger 3^^^^3. The proper way to breakdown G1/3^^^^3 is 3^^^(3^^^3) where 3^^^3 is the result a tower of 3's 7625597484987 "3's" high, as established earlier. So that's 3^^^(7625597484987 3's tower). Since 3^^^3 basically tells you to build a huge tower, the next step is to take the result of calculating the 7625597484987 3's and build that many towers to give you the number of 3's in G1. Note that the next step up, or adding an arrow, tells you not to build a bigger tower, but to build an exponential number of towers, or, in other words, to pentate them.

note: this is due to the fact that hexation (ie 3^^^^3) involves power tower building (towers of exponent stacks) where pentation 3^^^3 is  repeated tetration. Also note that tetration is simply repeated exponentiation.

Written another way 3^^^^3 = 3^^^(3^^^3) = 3^^^(3^^(3^^(3^^(....)). The number of 3's in parentheses is 3^^^3. *Remember, this is because 3^^^3 can be rewritten as 3^^(3^^3)*.

Using (3^^(3^^(3^^(....3)) and starting from the rightmost 3 you start building towers, and you end up building 3^^7625597484987 of them.

So... from right to left

Tower 1 is 27
Tower 2 is 7625597484987
Tower 3 is The result of a tower 7625597484987 3's high
Each subsequent tower is as high (number of 3's tall) as the resulting number above it.

Each tower increases the number beyond belief, and you repeat this tower building until you end up with 3^^ (the final result of 3^^7625597484987 towers). Then you have your true power tower height, which is now an ungodly number of 3's tall. Let's call that V*. So you have 3^^^V*. Well you already did 3^^^3 before. That just means you have a tower 3's now V* high, and V* is a really big number. Work that out and you have G1. So no, 3^^^^3 is not merely 3^7625597484987. It's way, way way bigger than that.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, I implemented hyperoperators in python as the module [`hyperop`](https://github.com/thoppe/python-hyperoperators) and one of my examples is Graham's number:

```
def GrahamsNumber():
    # This may take awhile...
    g = 4
    for n in range(1,64+1):
        g = hyperop(g+2)(3,3)
    return g
```

The magic is in the recursion, which loosely stated looks like `H[n](x,y) = reduce(lambda x,y: H[n-1](y,x), [a,]*b)`.

To answer your question, this function (in theory) will calculate the number in question. Since there is no way this program will ever finish before the heat death of the Universe, you gain more of an understanding from the "function" itself than the actual value.